# creating objects in static methods with private constructors

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    static A& create(int i)
    {
        A a(i);
        return a; // Ignore this problem.
    }

    void print() { cout<< _a <<endl; }
private:
    A(int i):_a(i){}
    int _a;
};
int main()
{
    A& a = A::create(2);
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand few things:

- Since a static method is not related to a specific instance, i don't
  understand how its possible to create an A object which has a private
  constructor.
- static methods can work only with static variables and methods. Aside
  to the fact that it is private, how come the constructor (is it a
  implicitly static?) can be called?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How come a static function is allowed to declare an `int`, even though ints aren't static?

Comment: it's not true that static methods can only work with static variables and methods. They just cannot work on the object *this* instance, because it doesn't exist. It is free to create new instances or use instances passed in and call private methods if it is of the same class.

Comment: Why returning reference to local variable instead of by value ?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey You should have written it as the answer.

Comment: _`// Ignore this problem.`_ Huh??, Why you're exposing code that shows that problem then?

Comment: its just a part of a question i got im my homework....

Comment: @AlexGoft Anyway any person that seriously attempts to answer your question, can't ignore that problem. It's essential for getting it right. What you're asking actually is bogus, because there are serious misconceptions from your side, what `private` actually means in the context of a `static` scope. In short: You are barking up the wrong tree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since a static method is not related to a specific instance, i don't understand how its possible to create an A object which has a private constructor.

static method which is in A class definition, has access to private constructor. In case your sample:

```
static A& create(int i)
{
    A a(i);
    return a; // Ignore this problem.
}
```

you are returning reference to local variable which is UB (is it the reason for your comment above?). Maybe you meant `static A create(int i)` or with `std::unique_ptr`:

```
static std::unique_ptr<A> create(int i) {
    return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(num));
}
```

or a singleton (but name create() indicates its rather factory method):

```
static A& create(int i)
{
    static A a(i);
    return a; // Ignore this problem.
}
```

> static methods can work only with static variables and methods. Aside to the fact that it is private, how come the constructor (is it a implicitly static?) can be called?

as I said above, your static method has access to private methods of your class. Constructor is called because you are creating local variable on stack, its legal.

Comment: Maybe the overall better solution would be returning a `std::unique_ptr<A>` from the `create()` function (changing it's signature of course). Supposed the OP doesn't want a Singleton, that seems to become more consistent from a semantical point of view.